# My mediawiki page displayed index of/ after updating to apache 2.4.23

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, mediawiki

I had this problem with MediaWiki after updating apache
At first, i installed using yum and i had apache 2.4.6, php 5.4 on my Centos7

Then i want to update them to latest version which is apache 2.4.23 and PHP 7.0
Until now, the only way to update apache is using source code. I removed the 2.4.6 and install new 2.4.23

Btw, the old DocumentRoot is /var/www/html
After updating, the new DocumentRoot is /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
I copy all the MediaWiki file from old documentroot to new documentroot. But when i access the server's IP, i just saw the index of/ and list of MediaWiki file.
How should i fix this?